# how to make an web application in demo in our comapny web site

Tags: asp.net

i  have  developed  an  web  application[ERP  FOR  A  SCHOOL].i  have    given the  build  for it is  working fine,  but now  i     need  to  provide this    web  Aplication in my   company web site  where   user's[clients]  can see  the  Web applicatin   .   now    what is  this  web applicationis  all a out.   our  application is  developed using   using  Sql Server 2005, .net  3.5(vs2008).
  now   i need  to  provide an  link  button  type in our   company web site. once the user  clicks that  link button.  a  new  window  should  open   which  will take  us  to the  web  Apllication demo[ERP  School Application]

how  to achive this.  any  idea  how  to  get it   done. what  are the  things that i  should  take  care here
any help  would   be  great

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new website in IIS and linking to it.

OR

Merge the website and application by:

1. Completely merging then into one system.
2. Creating a virtual directory for the application.
3. Making the Application the WebSite/Root application and creating a virtual directory for the website

Answer (score 0):

Whole this setup fully dependent on which platform your web server is?
sceneario1: company web server is on linux
1. You need to get permissions from you web administrators for editing pages and server login and passwords. You can use telenet to login on your company web server 
2. Create a new IIS (internet information server) on seperate windows m/c. setup this server with sql and web address. look in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323972
3. Add this new web address in your company web page as link.

sceneario1: company web server is on windows
1. You need to get permissions from you web administrators for editing pages and server login and passwords.
2. Check if sql is available on server
3. create new folder and put you whole web project in it.
4. Edit existing page from web.

This will not mess up any thing on your company server.

Answer (score 0):

Er, why can't you just create a virtual directory or a new site in IIS and put a link (with a target="_blank") to it on the parent site?